# How can i keep data array from checkbox when datalist has many page

Tags: php, sql, arrays

My problem is array can keep data only present page.
If user selected data page 1 & page 4 and push submit when he uses page 4
My array will keep data from page 4.
I want to keep data from the page that the user selects every page.

datalist table page

```php
<td>
    <center>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtID[<?php echo $ven2["id"]; ?>]" id="txtID" value="<?php echo $ven2["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $ven2["id"]; ?>
    </center>
</td>
<td>
    <center>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtACC[<?php echo $ven2["id"]; ?>]" id="txtACC" value="<?php echo $ven2["acc_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $ven2["acc_name"]; ?>
    </center>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="txtITM[<?php echo $ven2["id"]; ?>]" id="txtITM" value="<?php echo $ven2["item_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $ven2["item_name"]; ?>
</td>
<td>
    <center>
        <input type="checkbox" name="dataset[<?php echo $ven2["id"]; ?>]" id="dataset" value="<?php echo $i++; ?>">
    </center>
</td>
```

show data page

```php
    foreach($_POST["dataset"] as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($_POST["dataset"][$key] != "")
        {
            $DATA_ID = $_POST["dataset"][$key];
            $DATA_ACC = $_POST["txtACC"][$key];
            $DATA_ITM = $_POST["txtITM"][$key];

            print "ACCOUNTCODE = ".$DATA_ACC."<br>";
            print "ITEM = ".$DATA_ITM."<br>";
            print "========================== <p>";
            }
    }
```

My web template

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Comment: Post array for each page create a $_Post[‘Data’]=$array append all data to array like array push or $array .= ‘’; that will do the trick

Comment: my  each page is template from jquery. in this case what if I do what you say?

Comment: In the end keep collecting the date which user selecting for each page you can call JS and PHP because post method just in cache not the front page it shouldn't bother you at all